# ray tracing lighting

Tags: raytracing, lighting

I am trying to implement specular and diffuse lighting for a simple sphere ray tracing application, but I am having problems with my vectors.

I am trying to use the following to update the light, but the generated image looks exactly the same, so I know I am doing something wrong. I assume I am messing up the vectors in some way. Hit is the sphere that has been hit and mindis is the distance to this spheres point. Pir, pig, pib are the rgb for the color.

```
P3D intersection = ray.position.add(ray.direction).scale(mindis);
P3D l = intersection.sub(light).normalize();
P3D n = hit.center.sub(intersection).normalize();

double dot = l.dot(n);

P3D f = l.add(n).scale(-2.0 * dot);

double dot2 = f.dot(ray.direction);

pir += dot2 * 20;
pig += dot2 * 20;
pib += dot2 * 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the first line should be:

```
P3D intersection = ray.position.add(ray.direction.scale(mindis));
```

Also

```
P3D f = l.add(n.scale(-2.0 * dot));
```

f appears to be the direction that the light bounces off the sphere.  This would typically be the opposite direction of the ray, so you probably want

```
double dot2 = -f.dot(ray.direction);
```

Comment: The fact that the image doesn't change indicates some more basic problem.  Try to find something that does change the image.

Comment: If I manually change the colors, it does change, that component of the code is fine. The problem lies in my code above wherein it doesn't update the pixel color properly to adjust for lighting.